# Radio Buttons In React - I Have To Click Twice To See A Selection And Update State

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, radio-button, use-state

I am trying to update state with "yes" or "no" text that is chosen from a Radio button group. However, when I run the app locally, I have to click on the checkboxes twice in order to select a value. Here is a codesandbox example - which is having different issues than what I am asking this question for. Not really sure what is going on with the codesandbox chakra environment:

https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-cloud-buq9p?file=/src/app.js

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Stack, RadioGroup, Radio } from "@chakra-ui/core";

export default function App() {
  const options = [
    { title: "Yes", name: "yes" },
    { title: "No", name: "no" }
  ];

  const [itemName, setItemName] = useState("");

  const handleRadio = (e) => {
    setItemName(e.target.value);
    console.log("item name: ", itemName);
  };

  return (
    <RadioGroup name="radio-btn-group" defaultValue="1">
      <Stack spacing={4} direction="row">
        {options.map((key, index) => (
          <Radio
            onChange={(e) => handleRadio(e)}
            value={key.title}
            key={index}
            name={`${key.name}`}
          >
            {key.title}
          </Radio>
        ))}
      </Stack>
    </RadioGroup>
  );
}
```

Like I said, the codesandbox is acting a bit odd, but when I run the app locally, I have to click on the checkboxes twice in order to select a value. Obviously, I only want to click on a radio button once in order to select a value and update the state. If anyone sees what I am doing incorrectly here, please let me know.

Comment: Since your code sandbox is not reproducing the error, it's hard to debug. But just pointing out an existing issue in your code: the `name` attribute is intended to identify radio buttons in group, so both the yes and no buttons should have the same `name`.

Comment: at Jon: What version of Chakra UI do you use?
@ClaireLin That is not true, take a look here: https://chakra-ui.com/docs/form/radio#note-about-name-prop The RadiGroup should have the name property while the radio buttons should not have the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm - this doesn't work in the sandbox, but it does in my app: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-cloud-buq9p?file=/src/app.js

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Stack, RadioGroup, Radio } from "@chakra-ui/core";

export default function App() {
  const options = [
    { title: "Yes", name: "yes" },
    { title: "No", name: "no" }
  ];

  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const handleRadio = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setValue(value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <RadioGroup onChange={setValue} value={value}>
        <Stack spacing={4} direction="row">
          {options.map((key, index) => (
            <Radio
              value={key.title}
              key={index}
              onChange={(e) => handleRadio(e)}
            >
              {key.title}
            </Radio>
          ))}
        </Stack>
      </RadioGroup>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I think you are trying to implement a controlled input for the radio button, I would recommend you to try the [chakra-ui guidelines](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/form/radio#:%7E:text=Usage-,%23,-First) for the RadioGroup and Radio:

```
function RadioExample() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("1")
  return (
    <RadioGroup onChange={setValue} value={value}>
      <Stack direction="row">
        <Radio value="1">First</Radio>
        <Radio value="2">Second</Radio>
        <Radio value="3">Third</Radio>
      </Stack>
    </RadioGroup>
  )
}
```

As you can see on chakra's example, the **onChange** and the **value** props are being called on the RadioGroup component and are used directly from the useState hook. Is kinda hard to reproduce on the codesandbox but I think that this could fix your problem.